# No me carga el siguiente lvl

Tags: unity, unity2d

Teniendo este trozo de código , quiero que al acabar los 10 segundo me cargue una pantalla que tengo creada otra scene pero esta otra no me carga cuando acaba los 10 segundos, simplemente se para y se queda en la misma scena

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Timers;
public class Bird : MonoBehaviour {
    // Movement speed
    public float speed = 1;


    // Flap force
    public float force = 100;

    public double Interval = 10000;

    private Timer t;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
      // Fly towards the right
      GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.right * speed;
      t = new Timer(Interval);
      t.Elapsed += T_Elapsed;
      t.Start();
  }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        // Flap
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * force);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
        // Restart
        t.Stop();
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
    }

    private void T_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            t.Stop();
            Application.LoadLevel("win");
        }
}
```

la nueva scena se llama win, pero esta no carga, y tengo puesto "win"

Answer (score 0):

Buenas no se si esta correcta mi respuesta pero deberias en vez de hacer `LoadLevel("win")` cargar con la id del mapa, ¿como ves eso? en las opciones de build project, tienes que añadir los mapas shi y te indica un numero, ese numero es el que tienes que meterle a la funcion loadlevel, espero que no me equivoque y te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno para empezar ya no se utiliza `Application.LoadLevel()` ahora se utiliza el **SceneManager** aquí tienes más información:
[SceneManager API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html)

Pero básicamente deberias incluir la liberia de Unity.SceneManagement al inicio del script y luego usar

```
SceneManager.LoadLevel(1)
```

En el caso de que la escena que quieras cargar tenga **otro índice** (que puedes ver al abrir las Build Settings) pues substituyes ese índice por el correspondiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y lo de los 10 segundos no hay nada en este codigo para ello, pero he visto que ya lo preguntaste en otro hilo.

Comment: como puedo acceder a build settings?

Comment: Haces click en File y en el menú desplegable tienes la opcion @kit